# How to track users location for In-house symfony2 app?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Im building an In-House only web application based on Symfony2 and Sylius.  My company has 4 different offices with static IP addresses, and I want to track which office a user is operating out of.  Some employees move to different locations on different days, some users have laptops that travel from location to location within a day too.  Location will need to be referenced for almost every page view involving writing to the database ( the application needs to know what location an event is happening at ).

Im looking for suggestions as to how to best store and reference this info.  I will have a static list of IP addresses and offices they correspond to. This list can live in yml or a database table  ( we anticipating adding locations at once a year pace, so editing this list can be a manual task ).  Should this be something I just store in a session, or lookup every page load via $container->get('request')->getClientIp() in all my controllers, or create a Symfony2 ROLE and assign it with the  user on login, or ?  Other suggestions how to best accomplish this?

Im very new to Symfony2 still, so if there is an obvious place for this kind of logic, my apologies... I figured it would be somewhat unique since most public facing web-apps would not and perhaps in many cases should not track IP addresses the way I need to in this case... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to modify your controllers, just create an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and, on each request, do what you want to do.

To get the user, just inject the security context service and get the token. Then you can get the user if the request is behind a firewall.

Here is an example based on the official documentation (not tested and must be modified to fit on your project):

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/AcmeRequestListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class AcmeRequestListener
{
    protected $sc;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $sc)
    {
        $this->sc = $sc;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        if( null === ($token = $this->sc->getToken()) ) {
            // don't do anything if you are not behind a firewall
            return;
        }

        // do anything with $token to get the user and check he is authenticated
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // Client IP
        $ip = $event->getRequest()->getClientIp();
    }
}
```

And you service definition:

```
<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<service id="kernel.listener.your_listener_name" class="Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.exception" method="onKernelException" />
</service>
```

Comment: Thank you, This was my first ever "listener", seems to be working... This will work great to "set" the location data, but What would you recommend for when I need to "get" this location data ( IE when I need to write something to the database and record where it happened )  session variable? or something else?

Comment: ok, I injected the container into my EventListener and added this
 `$session = $this->container->get('session');
 $session->set('location', $ip);
 //$ip will change to a "location object" once I make it`

Then as proof of concept I decided to display the location ( currently just IP ) in my twig navbar

`twig:
    globals:
        location: "@astound.location_name"
services:
    astound.location_name:
        class: Astound\Bundle\LocationBundle\Manager\LocationName
        arguments: ['@service_container']`

Comment: `<?php

/*
 *  Injected arguments:
 *      - @service_container
 */

namespace Astound\Bundle\LocationBundle\Manager;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LocationName 
{

    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    } 

 public function getLocationName()
 {
  return $this->container->get('session')->get('location');
 }

 public function __toString()
 {
  return $this->getLocationName();
 }

}`
Is this a "best practice" way of "getting" and "setting" this location data?

Comment: Do not inject the container. It is a very bad idea as it will load a lot of other dependencies you do not need. If you need the session service,  just inject it :-D

Comment: Swapped out injection on both from container to session, still working, less code! Very good! Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, I do not think the session is a good place to store ip and user. You should create a entity and use doctrine to save and retrieve all activities of users.

Comment: Hmmm...  My current plan is to create a location entity ( or Model as Sylius calls them? ) and I want to have access to the location of the user, the same way I have access to the username.  Is it really a good idea to write this location/ip information to the database every time a user views a page or logs in, and then subsequently read from the db every time I need that info?  I wonder, Can I tap into the default Symfony login system and add a parameter next to username like locationId?  Like customizing what's found in the Symfony Profiler under Security?

Comment: Yes, create a location entity and create an access entity with relations to user entity and location entity. Your access entity should also have a datetime and a session id informations. You do not have to store these informations on each page. In your listener, just check if the session id is stored in your database. If not, create it. User <--OneToMany relationship--> Access <--ManyToOne--> Location